# endl or \n not working when outputting to file.

Tags: c++

```
ofstream writeFile;

writeFile.open("studentTable.txt");
writeFile << "hello" << endl << "bye";

writeFile.close();
```

I'm trying to output a new line onto my textfile "studentTable.txt", but after my program runs, my txt document says 
        hellobye

How can I fix this? I have already tried \n and endl. Thanks!

Comment: "hello\nbye" doesn't work?

Comment: try `\r\n` if you're using windows. Notepad has cannot display \n as well

Comment: cannot reproduce

Comment: Are you compiling and running your code on Mac or Linux, and then viewing the file on Windows? `std::endl` will create platform-specific end-of-line encodings, if I recall correctly.

Comment: @SlaneR that shouldn't be necessary. The runtime library will automatically convert `\n` to the correct line ending

Comment: Are you sure there isn't already a file named `"StudentTable.txt"` that contains `"hellobye"` you are looking at after your program runs?